# Ruby Ranges first and last issue

Tags: ruby

I stumbled over strange behaviour while playing with ranges, expected:

```
(1...1).count
# => 0 
(1...1).first(1)
# => [] 
(1...1).last(1)
# => []
(1...1).to_a
# => []
```

but

```
(1...1).first
# => 1
(1...1).last
# => 1
```

Do I miss something or is this intended behaviour?

Comment: It's probably intended. But well... look at Ruby specs. :)

Comment: It gives the expected output when you use an argument for first/last method. For an explanation check @ndn's post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that [`Range#first` is defined to return `Range#begin` if no argument is passed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a19830c42ce839ac1b4557cc30fe78757447f66c/range.c#L870).

Similarly - [`Range#last` => `Range#end`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a19830c42ce839ac1b4557cc30fe78757447f66c/range.c#L901).

Comment: thanks, ok I see it even stated in the comments https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a19830c42ce839ac1b4557cc30fe78757447f66c/range.c#L889, but not quite intuitive though ;)

Comment: IMO, it's broken by design. `begin` should return the beginning object and `first` should behave just like `Array#first` and `Enumerable#first` (same for `end` / `last`).